# How can I compile less to mobile or desktop version?

Tags: css, less, media-queries

My less-files contains media queries and I'd like to generate different css-files, based on media type. Like this:

```
lessc --media=desktop site.less site-desktop.css
lessc --media=mobile site.less site-mobile.css
```

Given site.less:

```
.logotype {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 30px;

    @media @mobile {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

It would output this for "mobile" (site-mobile.css):

```
.logotype {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
}
```

And this for desktop (site-desktop.css).

```
.logotype {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 30px;
 }
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: In short, nope. Less is not a CSS analyser/optimizer/extractor - there may be other tools for such task.